# Cannot comprehend Output Of The Program

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class asdf
{
    public static void main(){
     String temp = "165";
     int ch = temp.charAt(0);
     int ch1 = temp.charAt(1);
     int ch2 = temp.charAt(2);
     System.out.println(ch);
     System.out.println(ch1);
     System.out.println(ch2);
    }

}
Output:
49
54
53
```

I cannot understand the output.Is it implicit cast according to which a character is converted to a number . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to print characters, use `char` instead of `int` for you variables `ch*`.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing the ASCII values of the digits. 1,6,5.

Note that the ASCII value of 0 is 48. So, 49 is ASCII value of character 1 and so on.

Have a look here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Try this to get the actual characters printed instead of the ASCII values:

```
char ch = temp.charAt(0);
char ch1 = temp.charAt(1);
char ch2 = temp.charAt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a subset of `int`. It contains values from 0 to 2^16-1. Each value corresponds with a character.

When you assign a `char` to an `int` variable and print that variable, you'll see that `int` value that corresponds with the character.

```
'1' corresponds with 49
'6' corresponds with 54
'5' corresponds with 53
```

Answer (score 0):

it gives the ASCII value, you can cast it as char to get the expected answer

```
    System.out.println((char) ch);
    System.out.println((char) ch1);
    System.out.println((char) ch2);
```